# Deleting nested document from mongo array

Tags: java, mongodb

this is my mongo doc :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f22f6784aefaa97d7e533e"),
    "group_name" : "demo",
    "privileges" : [
        "User Group",
        "Profile Images",
        "Advertisement"
    ],
    "users" : [
        {
            "full_name" : "aap",
            "password" : "as",
            "status" : "Active",
            "user_name" : "as"
        },
        {
            "full_name" : "b",
            "user_name" : "b",
            "password" : "b",
            "status" : "Active"
        },
        {
            "full_name" : "prashant",
            "user_name" : "pt123",
            "status" : "Active"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all records having "group_name":"demo" delete particular record having  "user_name":"pt123" form users array. 
I have tried

```
 db.users.update({"group_name":"demo"}, {$pull:{"users.user_name":"pt123"}})
```

but showing no effect. Where am i lacking?
Please Help
My java code is

```
BasicDBObject del = new BasicDBObject("group_name", z);
del.put("users.user_name", x);
BasicDBObject delquery=new BasicDBObject("$match",del);
con.remove(delquery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      BasicDBObject sq = new BasicDBObject("group_name", z);
      BasicDBObject idoc=new BasicDBObject("user_name",x);
      BasicDBObject odoc =new BasicDBObject("users",idoc);
      BasicDBObject delq=new BasicDBObject("$pull",odoc);
      con.coll.update(sq, delq);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's working query for you:

```
db.users.update({"group_name":"demo"}, {$pull: {"users":{"user_name":"pt123"}}})
```